# Redirecting to another page when the user clicks menu item

Tags: jquery, html, css, model-view-controller

I need a way of redirecting to another page when the user clicks on a selection from a drop down menu. I have created the Drop down menu purely from CSS. I did try using actionlinks in the li tag but it only covers the area of text for clicking, i need the whole li to be clickable. I know there is a way of doing it in jquery but i've never touched jquery. I appreciate your help guys :)

```
     <li>Jobs
 <ul class="click">
    <li>List of Jobs</li>
    <li>Create a New Job</li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE

here it is in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L1ra7vtj/

i basically want the drop downs to redirect to other pages

Comment: you can set the `width : 100%;` and `height : 100%;`

Comment: Please post a complete code example. And what are "actionlinks"?

Comment: try making a quick jsfiddle to replicate the problem @j08691 action links are ASP.NET mvc helpers, they basically create the html for you to make it "easier"

Comment: @AbdulAhmad here it is in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L1ra7vtj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I looked at your code and it looks like because you have padding on all those

```
ul li ul li { }
```

this is screwing up any other tags you put in the `li` directly. Instead of having the padding on the `li`, I set the `padding to 0` and I added a `span` tag around every word that is not a "link".

and then I added in the first drop down an `<a>` tag (which is what an action link creates in the background) and I set the padding on those instead. That should fix your problem. This makes the link take the whole space of the `li', making the whole thing clickable (this is essentially the same thing that isherwood is saying as well)

If you want the drop downs to redirect to other pages you either put the text in the li in an `<a>` tag or you put the action link inside the li tag and give it a class so you can style it like I styled the `<a> and <span>` tags.

heres your updated fiddle with the changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/L1ra7vtj/1/

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much @AbdulAhmad :) i was nearly gonna give up and just stick to the action link method. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

You should still use anchors. jQuery scripting to replicate basic web functionality is a bad approach.

```
.menu li {padding: 0;}
.menu li a {display: block;}
```

Comment: this has been done in my CSS file..the click class was me attempting at doing a jquery. sorry for the confusion.